Crypto puzzles on Crypto.SE
I wrote a cryptanalysis puzzle.  It's pretty hard but pretty fun (in my opinion), and I'm wondering if people out there might be able to solve it.  But is such a thing appropriate for this Q&A site?  I'm worried it's not, so thought I'd ask here first.

No.
That is if your puzzle revolves around you coming up with some ciphertext and maybe some hints or something and want us to recover the key / the plaintext then this would be off-topic as 

Requests for analyzing ciphertext or reviewing full cryptographic
  designs are off-topic, as the results are rarely useful to anyone else
  and/or would be too long for this site.

and would be closed pretty quickly.
Of course there is Puzzling.SE which seems to accept just about any kind of puzzle, but be sure to read a bit on their on-topic page and also have a read of their specific policy on crypto-puzzles.

No, it doesn't involve a ciphertext-only attack of some obscure homebrew cipher.  But still it's probably not within the bounds of what we do here... I'll refrain. Cheers.

Maybe also link to the related https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/788/how-to-get-eyes-on-a-specific-cryptanalysis-puzzle ? ;)
